# Finding the polygon that has a specific point

Tags: geojson, geocoding, mapbox-gl, turfjs

I am using mapboxgl's geocoder to get the coordinates of a user's input. I have a geojson file that has data pertaining to the polygon regions, and I want to be able to match this data to the searched point.

I tried used turf.js, but I get a pretty generic error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

```
let pt = turf.point([ -120.459644 ,38.13742 ])

let data = geojson.features.find(d => turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, d.geometry.coordinates))
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there another way?

Comment: You have to pass the coordinates to a turf polygon constructor: `turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, turf.polygon(d.geometry.coordinates))`